# Problems when running a class in kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin

[newS8OOPSimpleClass.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f3qm.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJhmL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QJcr.png)

When I run this an error will be yelled at me "Redeclaration".

Comment: Can you provide content (screenshot, text) of `newS8OOPSimpleClass.kt` file?

Comment: i updated the question you could see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per screenshots, you have declared `Car` class in 2 separate files:
`newS8OOPSimpleClass.kt` and `newS8Constructor.kt`. You cannot do that in Kotlin. You have to remove one of them - probably one in `newS8Constructor.kt` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you so much appreciated.